# How to run batch command in my python script?

Tags: python, batch-file

I have to run a one-line batch command in my Python script.

Currently, I am saving my command in a `.bat` file and executing the `.bat` file using the `subprocess`. But I want to omit the `.bat` file and directly include the command in my `python` script. Because I might need to use different bat files for different use cases. I would prefer to use one dynamic python script than save multiple `.bat` files.

bat command:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\temp\FL.B5.exe" /s /a "C:\Users\kuk\Downloads\B5+Typ B.2.asc" /o "C:\Users\kuk\Download\B5+Typ B.2.docx"`

Python script was:

```
import subprocess as sp
sp.call([r"C:\Users\kuk\Downloads\test.bat"])
```

**What I want is:**

```
import subprocess

exe = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\temp\FL.B5.exe"
input = r"C:\Users\kuk\Downloads\B5+Typ B.2.asc"
output = r"C:\Users\kuk\Downloads\B5+Typ B.2.docx" 

cmd = '{} /s /a {} /o {}'.format(soft,var1,var2)

subprocess.call(cmd)
```

I don't know what is wrong, but unable to execute the script.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: What is `soft`? `var1`? `var2`? (Also, don't override python's built-in `input` function with a variable of the same name...)

Comment: Ah, that's my bad. I forgot to change the variable names. soft, var1, var2 are nothing but exe,input,output respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subprocess.call` method takes a list as an argument. When dealing with shell execution tasks I like to use the `shlex` library to quote parameters and split commands into a list.

**Note:** I haven't had to execute scripts on Windows for about 12 years so I'm not sure how compatible shlex is with the platform.

```
import shlex
import subprocess as sp

exe = r"C:\Program Files (x86)\temp\FL.B5.exe"
in_file = r"C:\Users\kuk\Downloads\B5+Typ B.2.asc"
out_file = r"C:\Users\kuk\Downloads\B5+Typ B.2.docx" 

params = tuple([shlex.quote(p) for p in (exe, in_file, out_file)])

command =  f'%s /s /a %s /o %s' % params

sp.call(shlex.split(command))
```

Comment: Is that mandatory to use `shlex.quote()` method? Is that making the command using variables or anything else doing? Why don't we  use a simple string concat and pass that string to `shlex.split()`?

Comment: `shlex.quote()` may not be necessary in your use case but it's a pattern that I have grown accustomed to using to ensure that each part is properly quoted for use in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

your question is ambiguous. if i interpreted it correctly, you can use `os.system`

`os.system` is a function which executes commands from console.

```py
import os

os.system('"C:\Program Files (x86)\temp\FL.B5.exe" /s /a "C:\Users\kuk\Downloads\B5+Typ B.2.asc" /o "C:\Users\kuk\Download\B5+Typ B.2.docx"')
```

Do not use `input` as a variable name. It is a python built-in function.